# RandomPoint inside mesh for walk-on-spheres Monte Carlo PDE solver

Tags: differential-equations, regions, computational-geometry, mesh, random-process

I'm trying to understand a Monte-Carlo Laplace/Poisson PDE solver:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/MonteCarloGeometryProcessing/paper.pdf

This method inspired by random-walks and ray-tracing has an advantage over FEM mesh methods in that it requires little to no mesh pre-processing.
I do not expect great performance from *Mathematica* but that's okay - I'm just trying to play with concepts in the paper.

I want to perform a walk on spheres in *Mathematica* shown in this diagram in the paper:

[image: walk on sphere]

**Questions**:

1. Given a mesh such as `mesh = DiscretizeGraphics@ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}]` how do I get a random point $x_0$ on the interior of the mesh $\Omega$ ? I've tried `RandomPoint` but it only gives points on the surface.
2. How do I find the closest point on the mesh surface $\partial\Omega$ to $x_0$ so I can then determine the radius $r_0$ of the first sphere?

Once I've got $x_0, r_0$ I can do `RandomPoint` on the sphere to generate $x_1$ and `Nest` this process until the sphere radius is below some threshold.

Comment: Replace `DiscretizeGraphics` by `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` and use `RegionNearest`. `RegionNearest[mesh]` generates a `RegionNearestFunction` that can (and should) be reused.

Comment: If I do that I get _"The first argument BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[] is expected to be parameter-free"_ when calling `RandomPoint`

Comment: Ah, the cow is not watertight. You may try `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "BoundaryMeshRegion"]` instead (it is already a `BoundaryMeshRegion` has `RegionDimension equal to 3).

Comment: With the above and `rnf=RegionNearest[mesh]`, the point `x0=RandomPoint[mesh]` is correctly on the interior, but the nearest point I expected to lie on the surface `rnf[x0]` is actually the same point `x0`

Comment: Ah, of course you have to apply `RegionNearest` to `RegionBoundary[mesh]`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Great! It works - you should have written it up as an answer - I would have accepted.

Comment: @flinty If Henrik doesn't write it up as an answer, then perhaps you could. As you probably know, self-answers are encouraged!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Henrik Schumacher I got this to work with `NestWhileList` and visualized the walk on spheres. The other outputs of `nextPoint` besides `RandomPoint` are for visualization and the termination of the `NestWhileList` when the radius is small enough:

```
mesh = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "BoundaryMeshRegion"];
rnf = RegionNearest@RegionBoundary@mesh;

nextPoint[p_] := Block[{r = EuclideanDistance[rnf[p], p]},
 {RandomPoint[Sphere[p, r]], p, r}]

walk = NestWhileList[
   nextPoint[#[[1]]] &, {RandomPoint[mesh], {}, ∞}, #[[3]] > 10^-3 &];

Graphics3D[{Opacity[.0], mesh,
  Opacity[1], Red, Thick, Line[walk[[All, 1]]],
  Blue, Opacity[0.04], 
  Sphere[#[[2]], #[[3]]] & /@ Rest[walk]}]
```

[image: walk on spheres triceratops mesh]

And with simple modifications it works for 2D, here demonstrated with a random polygon:

```
reg = RandomPolygon[12];
rnf = RegionNearest@RegionBoundary@reg;

nextPoint[p_] := 
 Block[{r = EuclideanDistance[rnf[p], p]}, {RandomPoint[Circle[p, r]], p, r}]

walk = NestWhileList[
   nextPoint[#[[1]]] &, {RandomPoint[reg], {}, ∞}, #[[3]] > 10^-5 &];

Graphics[{Opacity[.1], reg, Opacity[1], Red, Thick, 
  Line[walk[[All, 1]]], Blue, Opacity[0.04], 
  Disk[#[[2]], #[[3]]] & /@ Rest[walk]}]
```

[image: walk on circles random polygon 2d]

Comment: Love the paper, thanks for bringing it up in a Mathematica context! Would be awesome to see the whole poisson/laplace-solver working in Mathematica in case you are implementing it.